# How to embed metadata with in mpeg2ts

Tags: mpeg, mpeg2-ts

I want to embed metadata about a particular stream with in a mpeg2ts. which is the best field with in transport stream to embed this information. Can i embed this information with in the adaptation field of the mpeg2ts header.

Thank you
Guru

Answer (score 1):

Under MPEG 2 systems standard there potentially two ways to do this.

1. One can either define a *user private table*. See Table 2-26 : table_id 0x40-0xFE See. section 2.4.4.10 Syntax of the Private section.
2. Or one can define *user private stream*. See Table 2-29 stream id under PES packet as 0x80 to 0xFF).

Refer to ISO/IEC 13818-1 MPEG 2 Systems.